# pywin32: how do I get a pyDEVMODE object?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

How can I create a `PyDEVMODE` object without just having it as a return from a function call like `win32api.EnumDisplaySettingsEx(name, 0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in pywintypes.

```
>>> import pywintypes
>>> pywintypes.DEVMODEType()
<PyDEVMODE object at 0x00F38E90>
```

I'm curious as to what you are going to use it for?

Comment: ah ty, just found that out right now. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858366/pywin32virtualbox-guest-vm-crashes-when-trying-to-disable-second-monitor) for the use case =).