# setting default printer custom page size with python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, winapi, printing, page-size

At the organization I work for, different printers are set up at various locations. All are mainly used to print A4-sized documents, so the defaults are set up accordingly.

We are also using a bunch of custom-sized forms which people have up to now been filling in by hand.
Recently, I was tasked with setting up print-automation onto the said forms from our central database.

I'm using reportlab to create temporary pdf files which I am then trying to send to the default printer. All is relatively simple, save for getting the printers to register a custom paper size.

I got as far as the following code snippet, but I'm really stuck.

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print

pdf_file = tempfile.mktemp(".pdf")

#CREATION OF PDF FILE WITH REPORTLAB

printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}
pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer, PRINTER_DEFAULTS)
level = 2
properties = win32print.GetPrinter(pHandle, level)
pDevModeObj = properties["pDevMode"]

pDevModeObj.PaperSize = 0
pDevModeObj.PaperLength = 2200 #SIZE IN 1/10 mm
pDevModeObj.PaperWidth = 1000 #SIZE IN 1/10 mm

properties["pDevMode"]=pDevModeObj
win32print.SetPrinter(pHandle,level,properties,0)
    
#OPTION ONE
#win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", pdf_file, None, ".", 0)

#OPTION TWO
win32api.ShellExecute (0,"printto",pdf_file,'"%s"' % printer,".",0)

win32print.ClosePrinter(pHandle)
```

It just does not work. Printers do not report a "paper size mismatch", like they should when a non-A4 document is being sent to them. And when I try printing to a PDF printer, it also defaults to A4.

When calling

```
print(pDevModeObj.PaperSize)
print(pDevModeObj.PaperLength)
print(pDevModeObj.PaperWidth)
```

everything seems to be in order, so I'm guessing I don't know how to send those paper size values back to the printer settings.

Here is a list of all the resources I checked out (examples not all in python, and a few are not using the win32api), and couldn't get the thing to work properly:

- [Programmatically Print a PDF File - Specifying Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878616/programmatically-print-a-pdf-file-specifying-printer)
- [Python's win32api only printing to default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626918/pythons-win32api-only-printing-to-default-printer)
- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2005-August/003683.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/modify-printer-settings-setprinter-api
- [Print PDF file in duplex mode via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435973/print-pdf-file-in-duplex-mode-via-python)
- https://www.thinbug.com/q/39249360
- [Saving / Restoring Printer DevModes - wxPython / win32print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449142/saving-restoring-printer-devmodes-wxpython-win32print)
- [pywin32: how do I get a pyDEVMODE object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857884/pywin32-how-do-i-get-a-pydevmode-object)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/modify-printer-settings-documentproperties
- [How to change printer preference settings using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549573/how-to-change-printer-preference-settings-using-python)
- [Print file to continuous paper using win32print Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303945/print-file-to-continuous-paper-using-win32print-python)
- [python win32print can't set custom page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610277/python-win32print-cant-set-custom-page-size)
- http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyDEVMODE.html
- https://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/pythonicwindowsprinting.html
- [Printing a file and configure printer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688440/printing-a-file-and-configure-printer-settings)
- [Change printer default paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826507/change-printer-default-paper-size)
- https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-win32/085x5hdbtd/how-to-change-paper-size-while-printing
- [openpyxl - set custom paper size for printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481655/openpyxl-set-custom-paper-size-for-printing)
- [Python win32print changing advanced printer options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555453/python-win32print-changing-advanced-printer-options)
- [Printing PDF files with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385324/printing-pdf-files-with-python/51460044)
- [Python silent print PDF to specific printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195594/python-silent-print-pdf-to-specific-printer)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printerconfiguration
- [Printing PDF's using Python,win32api, and Acrobat Reader 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688028/printing-pdfs-using-python-win32api-and-acrobat-reader-9)
- [Python print pdf file with win32print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249360/python-print-pdf-file-with-win32print)
- [How to chose Paper Format when printing a PDF File with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414372/how-to-chose-paper-format-when-printing-a-pdf-file-with-python)
- [Access denied when attempting to remove printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578005/access-denied-when-attempting-to-remove-printer)
- https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/24860/win32api.ShellExecute
- https://opensource.gonnerman.org/?p=192
- [Python27 - on windows 10 how can i tell printing paper size is 50.8mm x 25.4mm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178454/python27-on-windows-10-how-can-i-tell-printing-paper-size-is-50-8mm-x-25-4mm)
- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-May/007640.html
- http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Comment: Using the shell to print is pretty flaky. If you spoke to the printer directly you'd be able to control the paper. I suspect your real problem is actually having chosen the wrong way to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShellExecute` is using the default printing parameters. If you need to use the reset `DevMode` for printing, you can use `CreateDC`.

Refer: [GDI Print API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/gdi-printing)

---

> If you use SetPrinter to modify the default DEVMODE structure for a
> printer (globally setting the printer defaults), you must first call
> the [DocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/documentproperties) function to validate the DEVMODE structure.

Refer:

- [SetPrinter Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setprinter#remarks)
- [Modify printer settings by using the SetPrinter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045704/change-printer-tray-with-pywin32)

You can also directly use `DocumentProperties` to modify printer initialization information.

Then pass `pDevModeObj` to `CreateDC`, and use `StartDoc` and `StartPage` to print.

Similar case: [Change printer tray with pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045704/change-printer-tray-with-pywin32)

Comment: @Jure T Hi, please tell me if the answer useful to you?

Comment: Dear Strive Sun! I apologize for a late reply. Your answer did help, ... ironically by making me re-evaluate my approach and go back to the basics. :)
... so ...
I ended up using the wxwidgets wrapper for page creation and for sending it to the prinder. Somehow, the page size and all works when I use, as I said, wxwidgets. ... To anyone failing to properly do what StriveSun suggested, which I guess works, but I just don't get it, you can try changing your approach altogether.

Comment: ... just don't ask me what happens in the background in wxwidgets :).